# Dynamic Button Icon Windows app

Tags: button, uwp

I'm trying to do a pause/play button windows 10 app.

So far I know 3 ways to set the button using

button.context = "some segoe code"  - works fine when I initialize it with the button but on the code to change the context the button appears as a bunch of squares

Button symbolicon - works fine initializing but no idea how to alter the symbolicon value outside of button declaration

button uri - only thing I could find online about button changing, but I don't have the button libraries that come in windows phone...

what is your recommendations so on clickrelease the button changes to either the pause or the play

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have used **SymbolIcon** to achieve the toggle play/pause.

**XAML:**

```
<Button Click="play_Click">
    <SymbolIcon x:Name="play" Symbol="Play"/>
</Button>
```

**C# code behind:**

```
private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (play.Symbol.Equals(Symbol.Play))
    {
        play.Symbol = Symbol.Pause;
    }
    else if (play.Symbol.Equals(Symbol.Pause))
    {
        play.Symbol = Symbol.Play;
    }
}
```

Comment if you encounter any issues.